# How to show a window after closing another in separate Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on a login in visual studio and I'm using forms. The thing is that I need to have the option of showing the database of usernames and passwords. So what I had in mind is that only admins can see this database. The thing is that I can wrap my mind around what I need to do. I wanted to show as dialog the Admins permission form and then show the database.

```
private void HMnuShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrmAdminUser admin = new FrmAdminUser();
    admin.ShowDialog();
    FrmUsuer data = new FrmUser();
    tCData.TabPages.Add(data);
}
```

This code is part of my main form (Login), then as you can see it opens another form (Admin Confirmation) The Admin Confirmation has the one button (I haven't made the databases) but the tCData shows regardless of the Admin Form. Can someone help me to stop that from happening?

P.s:
I was thinking of using an if for this part

```
FrmUsuer data = new FrmUser();
tCData.TabPages.Add(data);}
```

but I have no clue for the condition.

[image]

Comment: How do we know if the current user is admin or not? is `FrmAdminUser` validating if the user has admin privileges, or was that determined earlier somehow?

Comment: I'm using sql server for the admin's database. The idea is to show the for as a dialog that asks for the user admin and their password, then they can delete or review the users database. I have this same problem with my log in button, because even in the user is wrong or if the log in form is closed, they still can log in.

Comment: We understand what the "big idea" is. You didn't answer the question, though.  Is `FrmAdminUser();` what they login with, or what Admin is supposed to see AFTER they've already logged in? Where are you validating that the user is an admin?...

Comment: `FrmAdminUser();`  It's what they log in with.

public class ApplicationDbContextUsuario : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContextUsuario()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data  ;
                                         Initial Catalog=MayasoftUsuarios;
                                         User Id=;
                                         Password=");
        }

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out. If the answer works, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

> FrmAdminUser(); It's what they log in with.

Awesome. So you need to capture the RETURN VALUE of `admin.ShowDialog()`, which is of type `DialogResult`.

In FrmAdminUser you need to set `DialogResult` to OK only if they successfully login:

```
// In FrmAdminUser, when they SUCCESSFULLY login:
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

This causes code execution to return to the `ShowDialog()` line where you can now make that DECISION you were wanting:

```
FrmAdminUser admin = new FrmAdminUser();
if (admin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    FrmUsuer data = new FrmUser();
    tCData.TabPages.Add(data);
}
```

If they cancel the login dialog, or you set `DialogResult` to something other than "OK", then they will not see `FrmUser` appear.